# Oracle SQL: How to INSERT a SELECT statement with a GROUP BY clause on a table with IDENTITY column?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

In an application, I intend on truncating and inserting on an Oracle 12c database, but have found this issue with an `IDENTITY` column. Even though the `INSERT... SELECT` statement works on most `SELECT` uses I have tried, when this statement also has a `GROUP BY` clause, it fails to work, issuing a "ORA-00979: not a `GROUP BY` expression" complaint. Below is some example code:

```
create table aux (
  owner_name varchar2(20),
pet varchar2(20) );

insert into aux values ('Scott', 'dog');
insert into aux values ('Mike', 'dog');
insert into aux values ('Mike', 'cat');
insert into aux values ('John', 'turtle');

create table T1 (
  id number generated always as identity,
  owner_name varchar2(20),
  pet_count number
);
insert into T1 (owner_name, pet_count) 
  select owner_name, count(*) as pet_count from aux group by owner_name;
select owner_name, count(*) as pet_count from aux group by owner_name;
```

It works on the first insert, but fails on the next.

EDIT: I've changed the code so the issue is easier to understand while still reproducible.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Does it work if you use `select * from (select 'Scott' from dual group by 1)`?

Comment: Identity columns are like sequences and are anyways distinct, what is the business requirement for grouping on identity columns ?

Comment: I have already tried that encapsulated select, but the issue remains.
@vishad I want to group on other columns, not on the identity, to have a single entry for the other columns, then pass this entry to the new table along with the identity.

Comment: Very interesting error.  As a workaround, would using this query give you the same results you are seeking? `select distinct 'Scott' from dual`

Comment: GROUP BY 1 isn't valid syntax. Use GROUP BY NAMES.

Comment: After your edit both of the queries look the same to me?

Comment: They are the same, just to show the problem isn't in the `group by` code, but in it's interaction with the insert itself. Run both, you can see the `select`statement works, but not the `insert`.

Answer (score 6):

In the Oracle Community, this question has been answered.
https://community.oracle.com/message/13227544#13227544

```
insert into T1 (owner_name, pet_count)
with t as (select /*+ materialize */ owner_name, count(*) as pet_count from aux group by owner_name)
select owner_name, pet_count from t
```

Quoting the original answer, keep in mind the materialize hint is not documented.
Thanks to all for your help!